# any widgets for tag cloud that takes JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, tag-cloud

i was wondering if anyone knew any widgets for creating a tag cloud that takes in JSON objects? i have an array of JSON objects and was wondering whats the best way to create a tag cloud from it? thanks a bunch = )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tagcloud/